# HTML website url contains /#[object Object] when navigating

Tags: html

I have a website and it contains the following code:

```
<li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
```

and the appropriate section:

```
<section class="section" id="services">
    ...
</section>
```

When I press the `li` element, the page scrolls to the `services` section as expected however, the url is appended with `/#[object Object]` instead of `/services`.

Here's an image:
[image]

Any idea about what the issue may be?

**EDIT**: Sorry, forgot to add the javascript: The issue was the `new_target` variable. I had to change it to `new_target` as it was also `target` before and that fixed the issue!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(document).off("scroll");

      $("a").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
      });
      $(this).addClass("active");

      var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
        
      var new_target = $(this.hash);
      $("html, body")
        .stop()
        .animate(
          {
            scrollTop: new_target.offset().top - 79
          },
          500,
          "swing",
          function() {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
          }
        );
    });
  });
```

Comment: You have not posted any script that you use to scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question doesn't allows us to examine the problem in big detail but here is *-at a glance-* what is going on:

> You are trying to assign an object to a place where only strings are valid.

Take a look at the following example:

```js
function changeText() {
  document.getElementById("input").value = "hello"
}

function changeTextWrong() {
  document.getElementById("input").value = {link: "hello"}
}
```

```html
<input id="input" value="sample text"/>
<button onclick="changeText()">change text (OK)</button>
<button onclick="changeTextWrong()">change text (WRONG)</button>
```

When the input text (equivalent to the url bar) receives the text "hello" it works because "hello" is a text. However when the input text receives an object, this object is then converted into a string. Any object converted into a string is equivalent to "[object Object]".

Solution? Instead of doing `window.location.hash = object` you very likely need to do something like `window.location.hash = object.hash`, or `window.location.hash = object.WhAtEvEr` depending on the object's actual content.

Answer (score 1):

i think you tried to simplify the question without presenting us the complete or relevant code.
From your example, if you only do that it should work but i have a feeling that your code is doing more than that.

@adelriosantiago was right in pointing out that you might return an object instead of the expected string.